# Why Xcode runs the older version of my project both on iOS Simulator and the Device?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

When running Xcode shows older version of the project both on iOS simulator and iOS Device! It never shows the new background picture I have added although it's there in the storyboard and saved!

I tried cleaning the project even with the option key pressed but still!
I have localizations and it was working well!

What could it be? Where is the problem?
I tried searching but I ran out of terms and still no effective results.

Comment: Did you delete the app completely from the simulator & device and re-run it? If you did that any the image is still the old one, then something is wrong in your storyboard/code

Comment: Look in the project directory.  How many .xcodeproj files are there?  Is there a .xcworkspace file?

Comment: @RyanG yes I have deleted it on both simu and device.. Interestingly I have also deleted the reference to the storyboard and ran without it.. It still shows it!!!

Comment: @HotLicks I looked it up in the finder and there was only one .xcodeproj in that folder and no whatsoever .xcworkspace file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes apps get "stuck" in the simulator. Try deleting it (long press, then click the "x") and then check `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[ios version]/Applications` to see if it still exists. If it does, just delete it.

You can also try `iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...`.

Comment: i did actually delete it on the simulator and the device and did the resetting the content and settings but still shows the same thing! I wonder if it was the storyboard itself is not functioning well!!?

Comment: I worked it out by deleting the UIImageView and applying it again :)

Comment: I know that this is the accepted answer, but I would have to add that doing a Product>Clean or Command-Option-Shift-K likely would have resolved your problem without deleting + re-adding views

Comment: @StephenGroom Quite possibly. I really have no idea why my answer was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where an old storyboard were used on device instead of the most updated one I was working on.

The problem was due to the localization, I had my storyboard localized in 2 different languages and the device were using the storyboard localized in an other language than the default one which was somehow outdated.

Hope it helps.